# How to reset seconds in timer

Tags: java, android

Ho to reset seconds (it's "i" variable) when it's over 60? I tried to put it into the if but it didn't work.

```
SeekBar bar=findViewById(R.id.seekBar2);
final TextView textView=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);


bar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int i, boolean b) {
        int minute=0;
        if(i>60) {
            minute++;
        }

        textView.setText(String.valueOf(minute)+":"+String.valueOf(i));

    }

    @Override
    public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want the variable i to become 0 when it reaches 60,you just need to apply ' % ' modulus operator.

for ex:

```
i = i % 60
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to reset the `SeekBar`, simply use `seekbar.setProgress(0);`

### Example

```
@Override
    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int i, boolean b) {
        int minute=0;
        if(i>60) {
            seekbar.setProgress(0); //will reset the seekbar
            minute++;
        }
```

Comment: But I want to set i=0 when i==60. It's just a simple timer app.

Comment: @Szymon you wrote in the question that you tried setting i to zero and it didn’t work. What I’m suggesting will set the progress (which is represented by i) to zero

Answer (score 0):

```
bar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
@Override
public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int i, boolean b) {
    int minute=0;
    if(i>60) {
        minute++;
        i = 0;
    }

    textView.setText(String.valueOf(minute)+":"+String.valueOf(i));

}

@Override
public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

}

@Override
public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

}
```

});

Comment: But after i>60 and  i=0 seekbar doesn't make a progress

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate as

```
int minute = i/60;
int secs = i - (60 * minute);
textView.setText(String.valueOf(minute)+":"+String.valueOf(secs));
```